# Postgres - Cascading Deletes and Partial Indexes

Tags: postgresql, index

I am trying to optimize deletes from a table that results in lots of cascading deletes. Naturally, part of the process is ensuring that there is an index in place for each foreign key involved in the cascades. I used the query [in this excellent article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/) to get a list of foreign keys with missing indexes.

However, you can see in the query (and discussion) that partial indexes are intentionally excluded. While this makes sense in most cases, some of my nullable foreign keys have partial indexes that include `WHERE col IS NOT NULL`. While it would make sense (to me at least) that the cascading deletes should be able to utilize these indexes, I cannot find any way to prove it. There is no mention of this in the documentation, I could not find anything on the postgres mailing list, and using `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE)` does not explain the index usage of each trigger.

Does anybody know whether these indexes will be effective during cascade deletes?